# npx patch-package generates a huge patch with 'Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY' section

Tags: node.js, npm, patch-package

I am trying to patch `react-native-sqlite-2` with changing only 1 line on build.gradle but result of `npx patch react-native-sqlite-2` is a huge file with Automatically generated content like this:

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build.gradle b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build.gradle
index 81125f2..ea0fc40 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build.gradle
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build.gradle
@@ -27,7 +27,7 @@ android {
   ndkVersion getExtOrDefault('ndkVersion')
 
   defaultConfig {
-    minSdkVersion 16
+    minSdkVersion 21
     targetSdkVersion rootProject.hasProperty('targetSdkVersion') ? rootProject.targetSdkVersion : DEFAULT_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.6.2"
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/.transforms/7fd7aee232fc7aee8cc6fca98b62638c/results.bin b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/.transforms/7fd7aee232fc7aee8cc6fca98b62638c/results.bin
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..0d259dd
--- /dev/null
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/.transforms/7fd7aee232fc7aee8cc6fca98b62638c/results.bin
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+o/classes
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/.transforms/7fd7aee232fc7aee8cc6fca98b62638c/transformed/classes/classes.dex b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/.transforms/7fd7aee232fc7aee8cc6fca98b62638c/transformed/classes/classes.dex
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..24f21d6
Binary files /dev/null and b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/.transforms/7fd7aee232fc7aee8cc6fca98b62638c/transformed/classes/classes.dex differ
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/dog/craftz/sqlite_2/BuildConfig.java b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/dog/craftz/sqlite_2/BuildConfig.java
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..0316deb
--- /dev/null
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/dog/craftz/sqlite_2/BuildConfig.java
@@ -0,0 +1,10 @@
+/**
+ * Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY
+ */
+package dog.craftz.sqlite_2;
+
+public final class BuildConfig {
+  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
+  public static final String LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME = "dog.craftz.sqlite_2";
+  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
+}
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/aapt_friendly_merged_manifests/debug/aapt/AndroidManifest.xml b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/aapt_friendly_merged_manifests/debug/aapt/AndroidManifest.xml
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..f744388
--- /dev/null
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/aapt_friendly_merged_manifests/debug/aapt/AndroidManifest.xml
@@ -0,0 +1,9 @@
+<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
+<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
+    package="dog.craftz.sqlite_2" >
+
+    <uses-sdk
+        android:minSdkVersion="16"
+        android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
+
+</manifest>
\ No newline at end of file
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/aapt_friendly_merged_manifests/debug/aapt/output-metadata.json b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/aapt_friendly_merged_manifests/debug/aapt/output-metadata.json
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..b5c53ff
--- /dev/null
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/aapt_friendly_merged_manifests/debug/aapt/output-metadata.json
@@ -0,0 +1,16 @@
+{
+  "version": 2,
+  "artifactType": {
+    "type": "AAPT_FRIENDLY_MERGED_MANIFESTS",
+    "kind": "Directory"
+  },
+  "applicationId": "dog.craftz.sqlite_2",
+  "variantName": "debug",
+  "elements": [
+    {
+      "type": "SINGLE",
+      "filters": [],
+      "outputFile": "AndroidManifest.xml"
+    }
+  ]
+}
\ No newline at end of file
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/aar_main_jar/debug/classes.jar b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/aar_main_jar/debug/classes.jar
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..437619d
Binary files /dev/null and b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/aar_main_jar/debug/classes.jar differ
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/aar_metadata/debug/aar-metadata.properties b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/aar_metadata/debug/aar-metadata.properties
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..d8560bd
--- /dev/null
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/aar_metadata/debug/aar-metadata.properties
@@ -0,0 +1,2 @@
+aarFormatVersion=1.0
+aarMetadataVersion=1.0
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/annotation_processor_list/debug/annotationProcessors.json b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/annotation_processor_list/debug/annotationProcessors.json
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..9e26dfe
--- /dev/null
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/annotation_processor_list/debug/annotationProcessors.json
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+{}
\ No newline at end of file
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/annotations_typedef_file/debug/typedefs.txt b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/annotations_typedef_file/debug/typedefs.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/compile_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/compile_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..573b464
Binary files /dev/null and b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/compile_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar differ
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/compile_r_class_jar/debug/R.jar b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/compile_r_class_jar/debug/R.jar
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..d6cd920
Binary files /dev/null and b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/compile_r_class_jar/debug/R.jar differ
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/compile_symbol_list/debug/R.txt b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/compile_symbol_list/debug/R.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..6ddd299
--- /dev/null
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-2/android/build/intermediates/compile_symbol_list/debug/R.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,1865 @@
+int anim abc_fade_in 0x0
+int anim abc_fade_out 0x0
+int anim abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom 0x0
+int anim abc_popup_enter 0x0
+int anim abc_popup_exit 0x0
+int anim abc_shrink_fade_out_from_bottom 0x0
+int anim abc_slide_in_bottom 0x0
+int anim abc_slide_in_top 0x0
+int anim abc_slide_out_bottom 0x0
+int anim abc_slide_out_top 0x0
+int anim abc_tooltip_enter 0x0
+int anim abc_tooltip_exit 0x0
+int anim catalyst_fade_in 0x0
+int anim catalyst_fade_out 0x0
```

I tried to read github issues of patch-package but haven't found something related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem, it is possible to provide a list of files you want to patch and it generates diffs only for this list.

```
npx patch-package react-native-sqlite-2 --include build.gradle
```